# Equal roots of a certain polynomial equation by changing the sign?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Is there a certain polynomial equations which when you change the sign of the equation the roots will still be the same? I wonder if there are, how can it be constructed using the algebraic properties?

Comment: "change the sign of the equation" - do you mean replacing $x$ by $-x$ in $f (x)?$

Comment: Particularly yes, for a certain polynomials.

Comment: Yes, there are. $x=0 is an example

Comment: @AshtineV NeitherNor has constructed a polynomial that is neither even nor odd with roots at -1, 0, 1. See the comments below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
the function $f$ is termed an even function.

Examples,
$$f(x)=x^4+x^2+1$$
$$f(x)=cos(x)$$
You can recognise such functions from their graphs because they have reflectional symmetry in the y-axis.

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: If a function is neither odd or even, can it have the possible roots $±a_{1},±a_{2},...,±a_{n}$?

Comment: That's a much more interesting question ! For a polynomial I'd have thought the answer is "no" but for functions in general I'd be more cautious and start thinking about how to prove it one way or the other. Why not post that as another question as I think it would generate more interest than this one has ?

Comment: I gladly appreciate your answer, thank you. I would think about it as you've said, it will generate more interest.

Comment: There are clearly more functions.  Think of f(x)=1 if x>2 and 5 otherwise. Neither even nor odd,  but same roots under change of sign (always there empty set)

Comment: Counterexample of a polynomial: $f(x)=x+1$, with $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,-1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (note the domain).

Comment: @NeitherNor Ha ! Yes, my "no" for polynomials would have to be surrounded by phrases such as "smooth", "continuous", "well behaved"...

Comment: @Martin I guess even then it's wrong. Remember that an even polynomial can have an odd number of roots, e.g. $x^2$ has the single root 0 with multiplicity 2. Now,  fix some odd number $o\gg 4$. Construct an odd polynomial O of order o with roots -1,0,1, each with multiplicity 1 (fill up with complex conjugated roots which we don't count). Now, construct an even polynomial E of order 4 with roots -1,0,1, where 0 has multiplicity 2. Set $f(x)=O(x)+\epsilon E(x)$, and choose $\epsilon$ such that $|\epsilon E(x)|<|O(x)|$ for all x.

Comment: @NeitherNor Can you give an example so I can have something to look at as I work through your logic ?

Comment: @Martin I am at my mobile and don't have the possibility to check, but try the following: $E(x)=x^2(x-1)(x+1)$, $O(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$, $\epsilon =10^{-100}$.

Comment: @NeitherNor It looks like $\epsilon$ can equal 1 giving rise to the function $f(x)=x^5+x^4-x^2-x$ which is neither even nor odd but has roots at $-1, 0, 1$. $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ and was built from $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)+x^2(x-1)(x+1)$. I take my hat off to you ! I plotted it on Wolfram alpha which I think I can share with this link : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28x-1%29%28x%2B1%29%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29